# store data in array from another class method

Tags: arrays

i have one method in class call Class1 like

```
' public void getEventFromUser() {
    int event;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    date.getDateFromUser();
    // od.inputday();
    // od.inputyear();
    time.getTimeFromUser();
    System.out.println("Enter description :");
    description = input.nextLine();

    }'
```

and i want to execute this method and store in array in another class
like

```
public void addEvent() {
    if (numEvent == maxEvent) {
        System.out.println("error…no more room to add events");
    } else {
        schedule[numEvent]=getEventFromUser();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < numEvent - 1) {
            if (schedule[numEvent].isEqual(schedule[count])) {
                isFound = true;
                break;                  
            }
            count++;
            if (isFound == true) {
                System.out.println("Event already exists-notadding");             
                schedule[numEvent] = null;
            } else {
                schedule[numEvent].setDate();
                schedule[numEvent].setTime();
                schedule[numEvent].setDescription();
                numEvent++;
                //schedule[numEvent]=schedule[numEvent].getEventFromUser();
            }
        }
    }
} '
```

so,how can i do this?
pls give me some solution

Comment: i am trying to get data from getEventFromUser() and store that data into array , i know that getEventFromUser() doesn't have return but there is any solution?

Answer (score 0):

getEventFromUser() doesn't return a value, which is why schedule[numEvent]=schedule[numEvent].getEventFromUser() is giving you trouble.

Without knowing a bit more about what you're trying to do, it's hard to say if you should have getEventFromUser() return a value or have getEventFromUser() directly store a value in a field in the class. (I'm guessing the setDate, setTime and setDescription methods do this.)